# Prove that $U$ is normal in $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $T$ be the group of nonsingular upper triangular 2 x 2 matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$; that is, matrices of the form 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & c 
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $a, b, c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $ac\neq 0$. Let $U$ consist of matrices of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & x \\
    0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $U$ is a normal subgroup of $T$.

**My attempt:**

$\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & c 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & x \\
    0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & ax/c \\
    0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & c 
\end{bmatrix}$

Let $t=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    0 & c 
\end{bmatrix}\in T$

Let $u=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & x \\
    0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

$\forall u\in U\ \exists u'=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & ax/c \\
    0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}\in U$ such that $tu=u't$

Let $a\in tUt^{-1}$

\begin{align*}
a&=tut^{-1}\text{ for some $u\in U$} \\
&=u'tt^{-1}\text{ for some $u'\in U$} \\
&=u'
\end{align*}

So $a\in U$

Thus, $tUt^{-1}\subseteq U$

So, $U$ is normal in T.

I request someone to check this because I'm very new to group theory.

**Note:** The last time I posted this question, the thread was closed because I hadn't posted my working. I sincerely apologize for it, and I am posting my working now.  I request that this thread be reopened so that someone may check my working for this problem.

Comment: Dear Thomas you can prove this by just applying the definition. By matrix multiplication verify that $yzy^{-1}\in U$ for $z\in U$ and $y\in T$. Yet you should not ask in that way. What did you try ?  Is it a homework ?

Comment: @mesel No, it is not homework. It's just a problem from my textbook. I know how to prove that a subgroup is normal when the group is finite, but this is the first time I've needed to prove that the subgroup of an infinite group is normal. I just wanted to know the general method for solving such problems.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand your attempt well enough to comment about it, but here is how I would approach this problem. To show that $U$ is normal in $T$, we need to show that for any $t \in T$ and $u \in U$, then $tut^{-1} \in U$.

An arbitrary element of $T$ is of the form
$$t = \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix}$$
The inverse of $t$ is
$$t^{-1} = \frac{1}{ac}\begin{pmatrix}c & -b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$$
An arbitrary element of $U$ is of the form
$$u = \begin{pmatrix}1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
So let's compute $tut^{-1}$:
$$\begin{aligned}
tut^{-1} &= \frac{1}{ac}\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}c & -b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \frac{1}{ac}\begin{pmatrix}a & ax+b \\ 0 & c \\\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}c & -b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \frac{1}{ac}\begin{pmatrix}ac & a^2 x \\0 & ac\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}1 & ax/c \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{aligned}$$
Since this is an element of $U$, we conclude that $U$ is indeed normal in $T$.